# JavaScript exit method

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript method that i want to validate a form

if the validation fails so

```
if (validationChecks ...... ){
    return alert("message")
}
else{
//proceed
}
```

however no matter what i do in the if the form still seems to submit, any ideas?

Comment: The jQuery(http://jquery.com) and it's validation plugin(http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) will help you much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you should return false after checking validation.

```
if (validationChecks ...... ){ 
     alert("message") 
    return false; } 
else{ 
//procced 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You have spelt 'return' wrong. Also, returning an alert will not work, you'll need to return false explicitly to stop the form submitting.

```
if (validationChecks ...... ){ 
    alert("message");
    return false; 
} 
else{ 
//procced 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Your validation must return `false` when the form is not valid, and if you're calling your validationin `onSubmit`, then you must make sure that you include a `return` statement there as well:

```
<form onSubmit="return validationChecks();">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to  `return false;` in the case of failure